# Laravel elastic search implement soundex

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-phonetic

I'm facing an issue on the elastic search that it's not able to search if someone types wrong spelling. I have done some R & D about [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex#:%7E:text=Soundex%20is%20a%20phonetic%20algorithm,despite%20minor%20differences%20in%20spelling.). Now I'm facing an issue to implement [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex#:%7E:text=Soundex%20is%20a%20phonetic%20algorithm,despite%20minor%20differences%20in%20spelling.) on elastic search. Please help me to do that, I've already installed [Phonetic Anaalysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-phonetic.html#analysis-phonetic) plugin on elastic search but how to configure the plugin with elastic search that will work with the search results.

```
'title' => [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'analyzer' => $language . '_analyzer',
                    'index' => true,
                    'norms' => false,
                    'term_vector' => 'with_positions_offsets',
                    'fields' => [
                        'raw' => [
                            'type' => 'keyword',
                            'normalizer' => 'lowercase_normalizer',
                            'index' => true,
                            'norms' => false,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a [custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) using [phonetic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-phonetic-token-filter.html) token filter and the apply this custom analyzer to your [text field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html).

Alternatively, if you want to search with mistypes you can use [fuzzy matches](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-fuzziness).

Comment: I've already done R & D on that but am unable to understand where I need to add that analyzer in the index or somewhere else.

Comment: Yes analyzer settings are index specific, you should [set it up](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) when creating the index (or in the index template if you use them).

Comment: I've updated a code block where the existing configuration has. Can you please help me how can I add custom analyzer here

Comment: Yes you should set up analyzer when you create the index. There are some snippets at the link above.

Comment: Thanks, @ilvar. THe problem is solved now. Thanks again.